# Mapping plotting coordinates to figure coordinates in Matlab

Tags: matlab, coordinate-transformation

To state it simply, how do I map a point in the **coordinate system used for plotting** to **figure coordinates** in Matlab?

For a more thorough explanation, consider the following dummy code:

```
figure(1);
axes('position', [0.1 0.1 0.8 0.8]); % define position of axis in fig coords
hold on;
box on;
xlim([0, 2*pi]);
ylim([-1.1, 1.1]);

% plot something
t = 2*pi*linspace(0,1,100);
plot(t, sin(t));
```

The limits of the axis are [0, 2*pi] and [-1.1, 1.1]. These are the plotting coordinates I refer to. The position of the axis is defined with figure coordinates.

Let's say I want to find out the **figure** coordinates of a given point, what should I do? For example, the point [pi, 0] should be at the exact center (at [0.5 0.5]). But what' the figure coordinates of, say, [pi/2, 1]?

I could easily write a routine that works in this specific case using the known limits of the axes, and the position of the axes. I am, however, looking for a more general solution. What if my plot uses logarithmic scales? What if it's a 3D plot? Etc. etc. I would imagine Matlab has a simple routine for this but I haven't been able to find it.

Also, is there a routine for the opposite direction, mapping from figure cooridnates to plotting coordinates?

**Edit**

What I'm trying to achieve, ultimately, is fancy figures. More specifically I want to put annotations at exact points.

Comment: Try this submission from the File Exchange [Data space to figure units conversion](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10656-data-space-to-figure-units-conversion). I don't think it works for 3D plots, but if you search the File Exchange, you'll probably find something which does.

Comment: I think that I would be good to have a little explanation of what you tries to achieve here. The reason I ask for that is that it seems you want to do the same thing as `xlim`, `ylim` and `zlim` does. If this is what you looking for, the code for this is actually writen in matlab and quite easy to understand. There is also a function called `zoom` which is a .p file. I am not sure how that works though. That would somehow require reverse compilation and there is no guarantuee that it will work anyway.